# Cannot Connect Remotely to all Servers Listed in an Array with PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell

I cannot connect remotely to all servers listed in an array with PowerShell script. I can access all except two of them. Here is the script:

```
Enable-PSRemoting -Force
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "xxxxxxxxx" -AsPlainText -Force 
$username = "NE\a_chermes2" 
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $password)

$Computers = @(
    "NESCH11",
    "NESCH12",
    "NESCH13",
    "GLXVWPPSCH00",
    "GLXVWPPSCH01",
    "TWPPNESCH06",
    "TWPPNESCH07",
    "TWPPNESCH08",
    "TWPPNESCH09",
    "TWPPNESCH10",
    "TWPPNEDB01",
    "TWPPNEDB03",
    "GLXVWPPSQL02",
    "TWPPNEWS03.ne.local",
    "TWPPNEWS04.ne.local"
)
#$Computers = $Computers[0]

Write-Host " " 
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computers  -Credential $Cred -Scriptblock{Write-Host "I am in server: "  (hostname)}
```

I get the following error message:

```
[TWPPNEWS03.ne.local] Connecting to remote server TWPPNEWS03.ne.local failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the 
specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access 
from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local subnet. For more information, 
see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (TWPPNEWS03.ne.local:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WinRMOperationTimeout,PSSessionStateBroken
```

Comment: The error message contains 3 concrete troubleshooting steps, and a recommendation to read [`about_Remote_Troubleshooting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_troubleshooting) (which contains even more troubleshooting suggestions) - how did following those go?

Comment: I checked all the WinRM settings on the remote servers as the error message suggested but to no avail.

Comment: So no blocked inbound entries in the firewall log on the remote? No failure to resolve the DNS name `TWPPNEWS03.ne.local` from the client? No missing SPN's for the remote endpoint in Active Directory? It'd probably be a lot faster if you detailed the specific steps you've already taken instead of letting me guess at what you haven't done :) Please [update your question and include all pertinent details](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78186620/edit)

Comment: It may be a different domain or you do not have credentials.

Comment: I see that I will need to make some changes in the Firewall on the remote server with the issue but since I am not the owner of the server I am not authorize to make any changes to its firewall inbound rules. Thus I will see if my helpdesk can assist me with that.